# Bash script - change value in only one column

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I have 1 file, for example

```
12341234 3,0
12341342 4,0
```

How can I print:

```
abcdabcd 3,0
abcdacdb 4,0
```

`cat $1 | tr 1234 abcd`

changes both column 1 and 2. How to change only 1 column and print all columns?

Comment: As an aside -- `cat` is best avoided; `tr 1234 abcd <"$1"` is both more reliable (works with filenames with spaces due to the corrected quoting) and faster (lets `tr` read straight from the input file, not from a FIFO).

Comment: @BelaVizer, eh? tr maps between character sets. The usage the OP gave works.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way to do this is to split the columns and then rejoin them with `paste`:

```
paste <(cut -d' ' -f1 <"$1" | tr 1234 abcd) <(cut -d' ' -f2- <"$1")
```

The `<()` syntax for [process substitution](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/expansion/proc_subst) is a bashism, but the required functionality from `paste`, `cut` and `tr` tools is all POSIX-specified; thus, the only thing we require to run that isn't part of the POSIX standard is bash itself.

Answer (score 3):

Perl to the rescue:

```
perl -lane '$F[0] =~ tr/1234/abcd/; print "@F"' -- file
```

- `-n` reads the input line by line
- `-l` removes newlines from input and adds them to printed lines
- `-a` splits automatically each line on whitespace into the @F array
- the `tr` operator works similarly to `tr`, but you can bind it by the binding operator `=~` to only operate on the first column (`$F[0]`).

Answer (score 2):

With GNU sed:

```
sed 'h;s/.* //;x;s/ .*//;y/1234/abcd/;G;s/\n/ /' file
```

Output:

```
abcdabcd 3,0
abcdacdb 4,0
```

---

See: `man sed`

Answer (score 0):

**`Awk`** solution:

```
awk 'BEGIN{ split("abcd", a, "") }
     { 
         len=split($1, b, ""); 
         for (i=1; i<=len; i++) printf("%s",(b[i] in a? a[b[i]] : b[i])); 
         print FS $2 
     }'  file
```

The output:

```
abcdabcd 3,0
abcdacdb 4,0
```